# JavaScript hasClass or is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know why the following code is not working. Basically I am trying to check that whether the `input` is containing a particular class or not.

For this I have tried the `.hasClass()` method and `.is()` method but both are not working. Is there anything else which is slipping from my mind?

```
var cdSearch = $('#input_search');
var modalSearch = $('#index-search__big__header__input input');
function cdSubmit(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($(modalSearch).is('border-is-danger') && $(cdSearch).is('border-is-danger')){
            alert('something is wrong');
        }
        else if($(modalSearch).val() === '' && $(cdSearch).val() === '') {
            alert('field cant be empty');
        }
        else {
            alert('it works');
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: BTW: `hasClass` is a jquery's thing, not Javascript.

Comment: Where in your code is `hasClass`?

Comment: @j08691 `hasClass` is implied. JK :P

Comment: First thing you should do is [read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, yes, jQuery is written in js, but js has no `hasClass` method.

Comment: ok thanks, guys for the reply I got my ans (.) is missing its working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not use the `hasClass` method.

Change it to

```
$(modalSearch).hasClass('border-is-danger')
```

If you want to use `.is()`, use a class selector, not a tag selector

```
$(modalSearch).is('.border-is-danger')
```